# Save a Json file in elasticsearch using spring data

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data

im completely new to ElasticSearch. I have a static json file which i need to save it in ElasticSearch. I want to know how can we acheieve this using spring Java. Could someone guide me with any learning documents /or any links please.

Answer (score 2):

> Could someone guide me with any learning documents /or any links please.

*Elasticsearch:*
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index.html

*Spring Data Elasticsearch:*
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/

> I have a static json file which i need to save it in ElasticSearch.

```
static static Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", "your_cluster_name").build();
static TransportClient transportClient = new TransportClient(settings);
static Client client = transportClient.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("192.xx.xx.xx", 9300));

client.prepareIndex("your_index_name", "your_type_name").setSource(jsonDoc).get();
```

> I want to know how can we acheieve this using spring Java.

```
//Create an interface like this.
public interface YourClassRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<YourClass, String> {}

//In your service implementation class do this.  
@Autowired
private YourClassRepository yourClassRepository;

YourClass instance = new YourClass();
yourClassRepository.save(instance);
```